# Работа с датой: найти промежуток времени

Tags: php, дата

Работа с датой.

Задача: Есть две даты 2013-09-24  и 2011-08-15 и нужно найти их сколько прошло за этот промежуток времени например 1 год 3 месяца 2 дня. 
я решил написать функцию, а дальше не могу понять что делать.

```
function calendar($date1, $date2){

$dates = array();
# Делим на годы, месяцы, дни.
$dates[] = explode("-", $date1);
$dates[] = explode("-", $date2);

print_r($dates);
```

}

1. Время регистации (Минимальное число)
2. Последнее посещение (Максимальное число)

   ```
   echo calendar("2012-09-11","2014-12-11");
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function calendar($start, $end){

  # приводим к общему виду любую дату которую введем в любом формате и режем на части
  $start = explode(',',date('Y,m,d',strtotime($start)));
  $end = explode(',',date('Y,m,d',strtotime($end)));

  $years = $end[0] - $start[0]; // сколько прошло лет
  $months = $end[1] - $start[1]; // сколько прошло месяцев
  $days = $end[2] - $start[2]; // сколько прошло дней

  return "Прошло " .$years. " лет " .$months. " месяцев " .$days. " дней.";

}
```

Только вот чтобы склонять слова на Месяц-Месяца-Месяцев, Год-Лет, День-Дня-Дней  надо будет отдельной функцией пользоваться.

Comment: спасибо за функцию

Answer (score 3):

Есть в PHP прекрасная функция [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime), которая переводит строку во время в unix-time. А там уже можно всё что угодно считать и делать.

Comment: Или http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php вам в помощь.=)

Comment: а strtotime (); как я понял возврашает символьное число (по умолчанию) это цифра сколько прошло времени от запуска первого unix'a или просто дата зашифрована туда?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого есть [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php) (PHP 5.3+)